# Execution tree structure in activiti for a multi instance case

Tags: activiti

In my process definition, I have a structure as:

```
<definitions xmlns="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:activiti="http://activiti.org/bpmn" xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI" xmlns:omgdc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" xmlns:omgdi="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI" typeLanguage="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" expressionLanguage="http://www.w3.org/1999/XPath" targetNamespace="http://www.activiti.org/processdef">
<process id="MyProcessDefinitoon" name="MyProcessDefinitoon" isExecutable="true">
    <documentation>Dummy documentation</documentation>
    <startEvent id="startEvent1" name="StartProcess"></startEvent>
    <subProcess id="MySubprocessId" name="MySubprocess">
        <multiInstanceLoopCharacteristics isSequential="false"></multiInstanceLoopCharacteristics>
        <userTask id="MyUserTaskId" name="MyUserTask" activiti:candidateGroups="dummyGroups">
        .........
        .........
        </userTask>
    </subProcess>
</process>
```

Process has multiple subprocesses possible.

When I start process instance with inputs for 2 subprocesses, I get following tree structure for the executions.

[image]

As can be seen there are 6 executions in the system. I am not able to relate it to the process definition structure defined above.

I expect to have 3 executions. First execution representing process instance, and then 2 child sub processes branching out.

But going by tree structure, it seems start event too represents an execution. If that is the case,I can accept that.

But other two executions I am not able to decipher. It seems user tasks too represent executions. I am under impression that a user task is part of an execution, not an execution in itself.

Inputs regarding this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

a is your main execution of the process.

In the case of a multi instance subprocess the start-event and the end-event is triggered n+1 times. So there is a sourrounding execution (b) for the subprocess-instances.
Then you have your n=2 two executions for the subprocess instances (c,d) and both contain a user-task which has it's own local execution scope (e,f).

Comment: Please add line breaks